# Update history state and redirect

Tags: javascript, html

How can I update the history state and then redirect to a new page so that the back button returns to the updated history.

ie:

- I go to search.html?query=test
- Update history to search.html?waitQuery=test
- Redirect to Google search "test"
- Hit back button, go to search.html?waitQuery=test

For context: At my work site we use a ticketing system and to speed up my workflow I've created a local script file and set it as a custom search engine in Chrome. It uses regular expressions to check if a query matches a ticket ID pattern and if so will redirect to the ticket system, and if not redirects to Google.

This way if I search something like "TK00123" in the address bar, it redirects to `http://ticketengine/query?TK00123` but if I search "hello world" it just forwards that query to Google.

I would like to be able to hit the back button after the redirect and get a sort of interstitial page where I could choose from some options.

This is what I have currently:

```
<script>
let ticketSearch = 'http://ticketengine/query?'
let googleSearch = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='
if (location.search.match(/\?query=(.+)/)) {
    let searchQuery = RegExp.lastParen
    history.pushState({}, '', location.pathname + '?waitQuery=' + RegExp.lastParen)
    if (searchQuery.match('TK\d+')) {
        location.href = ticketSearch + searchQuery
    } else {
        location.href = googleSearch + searchQuery
    }
} else if (location.search.match(/\?waitQuery=(.+)/)) {
    let searchQuery = RegExp.lastParen
    document.write(`Ticket: <a href="${ticketSearch + searchQuery}">${decodeURIComponent(searchQuery)}</a><br>`)
    document.write(`Google: <a href="${googleSearch + searchQuery}">${decodeURIComponent(searchQuery)}</a><br>`)
}
</script>
```

From everything I've read this **seems** like it should work, but I never actually get that history entry that I can go back to. The redirect wipes it out.

Comment: You need to store the location paths in the context api and go back should be picked from the state

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Could you provide an example?